# In java, I just use a variable of 'A' to replace 'A' in one line , but get a different answer

Tags: java

When I'm implementing the SOR approach with java, I find this problem:
when I do this:

```
Matrix mm = ((D.sub(L)).inv());
B = mm.dot(b);
```

The value of B is right. However, when I use:

```
B = ((D.sub(L)).inv()).dot(b);
```

I get a quite different value of B which is wrong.

I fell this may be a reference problem, but I can't get the exact answer.

This is the SOR method:

```
    public static Matrix[] SOR(Matrix m, Matrix b, double omiga) {
        Matrix D = getD(m);
        Matrix L = getL(m);
        Matrix U = getU(m);
        Matrix M = null;
        Matrix B = null;

        try {
            Matrix mm = ((D.sub(L.pro(omiga))).inv());
            M = mm.dot((D.pro(1 - omiga)).add(U.pro(omiga)));
//        This is right:
            B = (mm.dot(b)).pro(omiga);
//        This is wrong:
//          B = (((D.sub(L.pro(omiga))).inv()).dot(b)).pro(omiga);
        } catch (MatrixProcessException e) {
            System.out.println("3 Matrix process problem!");
        }

        Matrix[] matrices = {M, B};
        return matrices;
    }
```

And this is the Matrix class created by me (methods in it have all been checked and have no problem):

```
public class Matrix {
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private int rowNum;
    private int colNum;
    private double[][] m;

    public Matrix(int rowNum, int colNum) {
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
        this.colNum = colNum;
        m = new double[rowNum][colNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                m[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix(double[][] m) {
        rowNum = m.length;
        colNum = m[0].length;
        this.m = m;
    }

    public Matrix(double[] v) {
        rowNum = v.length;
        colNum = 1;
        double[][] m = new double[rowNum][colNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            m[i][0] = v[i];
        }
        this.m = m;
    }

    public Matrix pro(double lambda) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                m[i][j] *= lambda;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }


    public Matrix add(Matrix mm) throws MatrixProcessException {
        if (mm.getRowNum() != rowNum || mm.getColNum() != colNum) {
            throw new MatrixProcessException();
        }
        double[][] m1 = m;
        double[][] m2 = mm.getM();
        double[][] addM = new double[m.length][m[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                addM[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
            }
        }
        return new Matrix(addM);
    }


    public Matrix sub(Matrix mm) throws MatrixProcessException {
        if (mm.getRowNum() != rowNum || mm.getColNum() != colNum) {
            throw new MatrixProcessException();
        }
        return this.add(mm.pro(-1));
    }
  }

    public double[][] getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(double[][] m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int getRowNum() {
        return rowNum;
    }

    public void setRowNum(int rowNum) {
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
    }

    public int getColNum() {
        return colNum;
    }

    public void setColNum(int colNum) {
        this.colNum = colNum;
    }

    public Matrix dot(Matrix M) throws MatrixProcessException {
        double[][] m1 = m;
        double[][] m2 = M.getM();
        if (this.colNum != M.rowNum) {
            System.out.println("sss");
            throw new MatrixProcessException();
        }
        double[][] ansMatrix = new double[this.rowNum][M.colNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M.colNum; j++) {
                double num = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < this.colNum; k++) {
                    num += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                }
                ansMatrix[i][j] = num;
            }
        }
        return new Matrix(ansMatrix);
    }


    public Matrix inv() throws MatrixProcessException {
        if (rowNum != colNum) {
            throw new MatrixProcessException();
        }

        Matrix mm = new Matrix(rowNum, 2 * colNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2 * colNum; j++) {
                if (j < rowNum) {
                    mm.set(i, j, m[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    if (j - rowNum == i) {
                        mm.set(i, j, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Collections.calculateUpperTriangle(mm);
        Collections.calculateSimplest(mm);


        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            mm.proR(i, 1.0 / mm.get(i, i));
        }


        Matrix M = new Matrix(rowNum, colNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowNum; j++) {
                M.set(i, j, mm.get(i, j + rowNum));
            }
        }
        return M;
    }

    public void showMatrix() {
        System.out.println("\nMatrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public double[] toVector() {
        double[] v = new double[rowNum];
        if (colNum == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
                v[i] = m[i][0];
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This matrix is not a vector");
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

May anyone help me to get the reason of the problem?
Thx!

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), perhaps? I think it would greatly help. I acknowledge that you have provided an example, but I don’t think it is minimal.

Comment: I mean, you're putting these two lines one **after** the other, rather than one **or** the other. And some of your methods modify the underlying matrix. Obviously your first line will modify the matrices involved, making it so the second line operates on different data and produces different results.